# Sending Primitive Message across Internet using TCP/IP

Tags: networking, messaging, tcp

Is there a very primitive method or protocol to send messages from two machines not on the same local network? I don't know what is available, but is there a terminal or prompt method for sending plaintext messages over the internet? Is it simple enough to code it from scratch?

Can I send a simple plaintext message from one machine to the next (if I have that machine's information) and then toy around with adding encryption and other crytopgraphy methods as an exercise?

Answer (score 1):

You need `netcat` or sometimes called `nc`. It is on most Linux distros and OSX and available for Windows too.

Examples available [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/04/nc-command-examples/).

Documentation [here](http://netcat.sourceforge.net).

On a server, run

```
$ nc -l 2389 > receivedfile
```

to listen on port 2389 and write whatever it receives to file "test"

And on the client, send a file to that port

```
cat yourfile | nc localhost 2389
```

or send a message

```
echo Hello | nc localhost 2389
```

Once you have got straightforward file transfer working, you can send an encrypted file like this:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in yourfile | nc localhost 2389
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like [`telnet`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet#Telnet_data) will do the job you're looking for. It's the most primitive protocol I can think of for this use case.

> All data octets except 0377 are transmitted over the TCP transport as is. Therefore, a Telnet client application may also be used to establish an interactive raw TCP session[.]